# VBA to loop through access query to create multiple csv files

Tags: ms-access

I have MS access database with a query called qrycustdata that contains customer data. I have a custid field in the data and looking for a VBA that will split the record on custid and create multiple csv files based on each custid.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: What code have you written? What have you tried? What sample code have you identified?

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop through `custid`s and create temp tables out of `qrycustdata`
   data, one *custid* at a time.
2. Use `DoCmd.TransferText` Method to export tables contents to csv file:

   ```
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset  
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MIN(custid) FROM qrycustdata GROUP BY custid", dbOpenSnapshot)  
   Do While Not rst.EOF
       DoCmd.Execute "INSERT INTO Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0)) & " SELECT * FROM qrycustdata WHERE custid =" & rst.Fields(0)
       DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0)) , "C:\TempFolder\Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0)) & ".csv", True
       currentdb.TableDefs.Delete  "Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0))
   rst.MoveNext: Loop
   ```

Comment: Thanks Malan, I think this code need more work.  I have tried it in the raw form and I am getting an error

Comment: Hi @user3526768, I fixed code lining in the answer, and fixed an error in line `currentdb.TableDefs.Delete "Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0))`. What error do you get?

Comment: Hi @user3526768 I fixed some syntax in line `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0)) , "C:\TempFolder\Temp" & cstr(rst.Fields(0)) & ".csv", True`

Comment: Hello Malan, I am getting compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: Here is the modified code. The error occurs right at the top 2 lines


Public Sub CreateReport()
Dim rst As ADO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecrdSet("SELECT MIN(custid) FROM qrycustdata GROUP BY custid")
Do While Not rst.EOF

Wend
    DoCmd.Execute "INSERT INTO Temp" & CStr(rst.Fields(0)) & " SELECT * FROM qrycustdata WHERE custid =" & rst.Fields(0)
    DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "Temp" & CStr(rst.Fields(0)), , "C:\Downloads\Testme\Temp" & CStr(rst.Fields(0)) & ".csv"
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "Temp" & CStr(rst.Fields(0))
rst.MoveNext: Loop

End Sub

Comment: thanks for staying with me.  I am still getting an error on rst.Fields(0) inside this statement:
SELECT * FROM qrycustdata WHERE custid =" & rst.Fields(0)

Comment: Oy, pardon @user3526768 , it was a late hour last night... it should be DAO.Recordset. I fixed the answer

Comment: I changed this statement also  CurrentDb.OpenRecrdSet to  CurrentDb.OpenRecordSet ..It showed compile error on  rst.Fields(0)

Comment: @user3526768 `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset` - I missed the **o**. BTW, VBA is not case sensitive, the editor fixes Upper and lower case for Object and Method names, according to the the compiler has.

Comment: @user3526768 Please put the SQL `SELECT MIN(custid) FROM qrycustdata GROUP BY custid` in a query SQL view, and execute it. Does it work?

Comment: Yes, this works : SELECT MIN(custid) FROM qrycustdata GROUP BY custid and there are 584 unique custid in my data

Comment: What is the data type of `custid`?

Comment: the datatype is number

Comment: I am getting the error on Line 4 of your code after this line Do While Not rst.EOF

Comment: @user3526768 both recordset and SQL are based on the same query, try opening rst as `Snapshot`. I modified the answer:  `Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MIN(custid) FROM qrycustdata GROUP BY custid", dbOpenSnapshot)`

Comment: By the way @user3526768 , What error do you get at this line?

Comment: I still get the error. It says Compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: @user3526768 , What version of Access are you using? Please see in the VB editor, under **Tools** -> **References** if all references are fine, if nothing there is *Missing*. Please read [here](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-38.html), and in links on the bottom of this article about references for DAO objects. Please be sure to post your results ;) You coul also read some more [here](http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Recordsets_for_Beginners) about DAO.

Comment: I am using access 2016.  I have 4 references checked 
Visual Basic for Applications
MIcrosoft Access 15.0 Object Library
OLE Automation
Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine object Library
Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Comment: @user3526768 Please add a reference to *Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object library* or a higher number than 3.6.

Comment: I am getting an error when trying to add.  Here is the error> Name conflicts with existing module, project, or object library

Comment: @user3526768 I see no reason for the compiler not to recognize the `Fields` collection of a `DAO.Recordset` object. I use Acc2010, but as far as I know that shold make no differense.  I suggest you post this issue in as a new question. Seems to me the code is fine, and with correct references should do the work as it is.

Comment: Thanks for all your assistance thus far.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user3526768 See if you ca refer to *Microsoft Office **16.0** Access database engine object*, rather than 15.0

Comment: I couldn't find that one, but i have added MIcrosoft Access 16.0 Object Library

Comment: OK @user352676 , dose that make a difference? dose `rst.Fields(0)` compile?

Comment: not as yet. It is still giving compile error at the same place.  Thanks for not giving up